# Implementing compareTo() and Comparable-interface

Tags: java, comparable, compareto

I'm trying to implement `Comparable` and `compareTo()`, but can't seem to get it to work. I've been trying different methods but I don't really get it. I know I'm supposed to implement the comparable interface, and that I need to create the method `compareTo()` before using it (strange for me, coming from python to object-oriented programming).

I would like it to compare the ages of two humans, so I tried writing the code as seen below, but it seems I can't use compareTo(). I'm getting the error message: "This method must return an int type", but as I see it, I am only returning 1, -1 and 0, which *are* `int`?

Also, I know the print-row in the end is wrong. How can I change it so it says for example: "Name1, 25 yrs old, is older than Name2, 21 yrs old". In python I could extract 2 specific values from a list and compare them with some given method; I'm not sure how to do the extraction for 2 different values in Java.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

class Human implements Comparable<Human>{

    int age;
    String name;

    public Human (int myAge, String myName) {
        name = myName;
        age = myAge;

    }

    public Human() {
        this(randomAge(),randomName());
    }

    public int compareTo(Human o) {
        if (this.age > o.age) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (this.age < o.age) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (this.age == o.age) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    protected static int randomAge() {
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();      
        return randomGenerator.nextInt(99);
    }

    protected static String randomName() {
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        return "Name"+randomGenerator.nextInt(15);
    }

    public int getAge(){
        return age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "\nName: " + name + "\nAge: " + age + " yrs old\n";
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Human> randomHumans = new ArrayList<Human>();
        for (int j=0;j<2;j++) {
            Human randomPerson = new Human();
            randomHumans.add(randomPerson);
        }
        System.out.println(insert.something.here);
    }

}
```

Comment: The answer is simply that the compiler doesn't know that at least one of your if clauses will be entered and therefor thinks there might be cases where no return statement is reached. Change it to use an if/else if/else and it should work. Alternativly you could also just `return this.age - o.age`

Comment: you should use `Integer.compare()` to avoid overflow

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS I'm using `return this.age - o.age` in my code now, and it doesn't give me any error message. But when I then write `System.out.println(randomHumans.get(0).compareTo(randomHumans.get(1)));`, I get the output "38". Don't understand why, it should only return 1, -1 or 0. I think it's just returning the difference in ages.

Comment: You can simply use ternary operator which makes the code shorten in one line! here is the code :>>   this.age>o.age ? 1 :this.age<o.age ?-1:0

Comment: You misunderstand. compareTo documentation states that it "Returns a
negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object." Any returned number greater than 0 is treated as meaning that "this object is considered greater than the specified object"  so it doesn't matter if you return 1 or return 40562. The same is true for any negative number.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS I understand now, and I tried using it. See my edited main post, it's still not working correctly and I can't find the issue.

Comment: @armara It is working, you are simply printing the age of the first person twice instead of printing the age of the second person. ;) Change the last `randomHumans.get(0).getAge()` to `randomHumans.get(1).getAge()` to actually print out the correct age of the second Human.

Comment: Oh that's such a stupid mistake. Ok, thank you so much for the help, it's working now! Too bad I can't give you any points by up-ing your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So using three if-statements does not work, which is why I could have written an if/else if/else statement instead, but another simpler solution would have been to write this in the `compareTo(Human o)`-method;

```
return this.age - o.age
```

Then for the print in the end;

```
int b = randomHumans.get(0).compareTo(randomHumans.get(1));

if (b>0) {
    System.out.println(randomHumans.get(0).getName()+", "+randomHumans.get(0).getAge()+" yrs old, is older than "+randomHumans.get(1).getName()+", "+randomHumans.get(1).getAge()+" yrs old.");
}
else if (b<0) {
    System.out.println(randomHumans.get(0).getName()+", "+randomHumans.get(0).getAge()+" yrs old, is younger than "+randomHumans.get(1).getName()+", "+randomHumans.get(1).getAge()+" yrs old.");
}
else {
    System.out.println(randomHumans.get(0).getName()+", "+randomHumans.get(0).getAge()+" yrs old, is just as old as "+randomHumans.get(1).getName()+", "+randomHumans.get(1).getAge()+" yrs old.");
}
```